# Join and group_by tidy eval issue

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

I have the following function that I have put together. It works up until the last part (noted in a comment in the code) where it has to join the objects together. I don't know how to get it to work. I believe my main problem has to do with converting the colName argument into a string for the "by =" argument of the joiner function. In relation to the group_by function, I'm not sure if what I have put there in the curly brackets will work. If anyone could help that would be great!

```
   emp_turnover_fun <- function(data, colName, year = "2015") {
  
  # Convert colName to symbol or check if symbol
  colName <- ensym(colName)
  
  # Terminations by year and variable in df
  term_test <- data %>%
    filter(year(DateofTermination) == year) %>%
    count(!!(colName)) %>%
    clean_names()
  
  # Start employees by var and year
  fun_year_job <- paste(year, "-01-01", sep = "")
  start_test <- data %>%
    select(DateofHire, DateofTermination, !!(colName)) %>%
    filter(
      DateofHire <= fun_year_job,
      DateofTermination > fun_year_job | is.na(DateofTermination)
    ) %>%
    count(!!(colName))
  
  # End employees by year and var
  year_pos <- year %>% as.character()
  year_num_plus_pos <- as.character(as.numeric(year_pos) + 1)
  fun_year2_pos <- paste(year_num_plus_pos, "-01-01", sep = "")
  
  end_test <- data %>%
    select(DateofHire, DateofTermination, !!(colName)) %>%
    filter(
      DateofHire <= fun_year2_pos,
      DateofTermination > fun_year2_pos | is.na(DateofTermination)
    ) %>%
    count(!!(colName))
  #### PROBLEM BEGINS HERE
  join_turnover_year <- full_join(start_test, end_test, by = str(colName)) %>%
    full_join(y = term_test, by = str(colName)) %>%
    setNames(c(str(colName), "Start_Headcount", "End_Headcount", "Terminations")) %>%
    group_by({{colName}}) %>%
    summarise(Turnover = ((Terminations) / (Start_Headcount + End_Headcount)) * 100)
  
  return(join_turnover_year)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is using `str` which gets the structure of an object. Assuming that `colName` is passed as a string, we don't need any wrapping.  Inside the function it is converted to symbol with `ensym`.  So, either get the input (assume it is a string) before converting to symbol as a different object or make use of `as_string` from `rlang`

```
 emp_turnover_fun <- function(data, colName, year = "2015") {
  
  # Convert colName to symbol or check if symbol
  colName <- ensym(colName)
  colName_str <- rlang::as_string(colName) ## converted to string

  
  # Terminations by year and variable in df
  term_test <- data %>%
    filter(year(DateofTermination) == year) %>%
    count(!!(colName)) %>%
    clean_names()
  
  # Start employees by var and year
  fun_year_job <- paste(year, "-01-01", sep = "")
  start_test <- data %>%
    select(DateofHire, DateofTermination, !!(colName)) %>%
    filter(
      DateofHire <= fun_year_job,
      DateofTermination > fun_year_job | is.na(DateofTermination)
    ) %>%
    count(!!(colName))
  
  # End employees by year and var
  year_pos <- year %>% as.character()
  year_num_plus_pos <- as.character(as.numeric(year_pos) + 1)
  fun_year2_pos <- paste(year_num_plus_pos, "-01-01", sep = "")
  
  end_test <- data %>%
    select(DateofHire, DateofTermination, !!(colName)) %>%
    filter(
      DateofHire <= fun_year2_pos,
      DateofTermination > fun_year2_pos | is.na(DateofTermination)
    ) %>%
    count(!!(colName))
  
  join_turnover_year <- full_join(start_test, end_test, 
             by = colName_str) %>% # use the string
    full_join(y = term_test, by = colName_str) %>% # use the string
    setNames(c(colName_str, "Start_Headcount", "End_Headcount", 
             "Terminations")) %>% # here as well
    group_by({{colName}}) %>%
    summarise(Turnover = ((Terminations) / (Start_Headcount + End_Headcount)) * 100)
  
  return(join_turnover_year)
}
```

---

It is safer to do `as_string` as opposed to taking the input directly as string i.e. `ensym` can work with both unquoted or quoted values, thus if we are passing unquoted, then grabbing the input doesn't work i.e. it may need `deparse(substitute(colName))`.  Instead, first convert to symbol and then do the conversion back to string with `as_string`

Comment: this worked great! I also figured out I had a problem with the clean_names argument in the beginning. Thank you